# C linked lists functions program running into segmentation fault

Tags: c, list, function

I have an assignment to write some functions dealing with linked lists. The functions are:
insertFront - put a new node at the front of the list

insertBack - put a new node at the end of the list

print - print the current linked list

Max - return maximum value in list

Min - return minimum value in list

locInList - return the location number in list

I have completed my code and I thought that it would work but I keep running into a segmentation fault. I know that this means that I am trying to access a portion of memory that does not exist. I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

I have tried separating and commenting out functions and it seems like the program runs fine until I hit the print function. The print function does not print as it should and I am assuming that the segmentation fault occurs in my max min and locInList functions. There are no error messages from the compiler.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
        int data;
        struct node *next;
};
typedef struct node node;

node* insertFront(node* head, int d);
node* insertBack(node* head, int d);
void print(node* head);
int max(node* head);
int min(node* head);
int locInList(node* head, int x);

int main()
{
        node* head = NULL;

        head = insertFront(head, 5);
        head = insertFront(head, 4);
        head = insertBack(head, 6);
        head = insertBack(head, 7);
        print(head);

        printf("Max: %d\n", max(head));
        printf("Min: %d\n", min(head));
        printf("locInList 5: %d\n", locInList(head, 5));
        printf("locInList 9: %d\n", locInList(head, 9));
   return 0;
}

node* insertFront(node* head, int d)
{
        node *tmp = NULL;
        tmp = malloc(sizeof(node));
        tmp->data = d;
        tmp->next = head;
        head = tmp;


        return head;
}

node* insertBack(node* head, int d)
{
    node *tmp = malloc(sizeof(node));

    tmp->data = d;
    tmp->next = NULL;

    if(head == NULL) return tmp;

    node *end = head;

    while(end->next != NULL){
    end = end->next;
    }
    end->next = tmp;


    return head;


}

void print(node* head)
    {

        node *tmp = head;

        while(tmp != NULL){
        printf("%d ", tmp->data);
        tmp = tmp->next;
                        }
}

int max (node* head)
{
        int max = 0;
        node *tmp = NULL;

        tmp = head;

        while(tmp->next != NULL){
                if(tmp->data >= max){
                max = tmp->data;
                tmp = tmp->next;
                           }
                           }

        return max;                             
}

int min (node* head)
{
        int min = head->data;
        node *tmp = NULL;

        tmp = head;

        while(tmp != NULL){
        if(tmp->data <= min){
                min = tmp->data;
                tmp = tmp->next;
                        }
                        } 

        return min;
}

int locInList(node* head, int x)
{

        int i = 0;
        node *tmp = NULL;

        tmp = head;

        while(tmp != NULL){


                if(tmp->data == x){
                     return i;
                }else{
                     i++;
                     tmp = tmp->next;

                        }  
                        }
                return i;

}
```

Comment: Now is a good time to [learn how to debug your program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Now is a good time to take a close look at compiler warnings...

Comment: It also seems you have some misunderstanding about pointers, lists and probably some other things. Take a few steps back and start thinking about the code you have. How can you use `tmp` (for example) to iterate over a list pointed to be `head`? Especially if `tmp` doesn't point to `head`? Also think about what happens when you do e.g. `tmp = malloc(...)` directly followed by `tmp = head`. What happens with the memory you allocate with `malloc`? What pointer do you have after the second assignment to free the memory and not have memory leaks?

Comment: Please indent your code, it's difficult to understand, for example in your min function the return is outside the while, while in your max function it is inside the if.

Comment: Fixed the errors with my return statements. Thank you for that. I fixed the compiler warnings and have edited my code accordingly. Still running into a segmentation fault. 

Taking a step back to assess Some programmer dude's comment. Thank you.

Comment: @User_Unknown_3458 I can see that you are pretty new to SO therefore I want to tell you that it is not considered good behavior to keep changing the code in the question once answers have been posted. Please don't do that.

Comment: Thank you. I had no idea. Thought that it would be helpful. I feel like a jerk now.

Comment: @User_Unknown_3458 Don't feel like a "jerk". No reason for that :-) When joining a new site there is always some "rules" that you can't know about from day one so minor mistakes happens. No problem. Now you know and going forward you won't make that "mistake" again. Have fun. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several bugs in your code but here is an easy one to start with:

```
node* insertFront(node* head, int d)
{
        node *tmp = NULL;
        tmp = malloc(sizeof(node));
        tmp->data = d;
        tmp->next = head;
        return head;   // Sure you want to return head ?
                       // The first time you call this function head is NULL
                       // and then you return NULL
                       // How about returning tmp instead
}
```

Now a more complex bug:

```
node* insertBack(node* head, int d)
{
        node *tmp = NULL;
        node *end = head;
        tmp = malloc(sizeof(node));  // Why malloc two new nodes ?
        end = malloc(sizeof(node));  // Your code shall only insert one new node
        tmp->data = d;
        tmp->next = NULL;

        while(end->next != NULL){
            end = end->next;
            end->next = tmp;  // Here you destroy the list by inserting
                              // the new node in incorrect places.
                              // You don't want to do this until
                              // the end has been reached
                      }

        return head;  // Again ... this is bad when called the first time
}
```

Try this instead:

```
node* insertBack(node* head, int d)
{
        node *tmp = malloc(sizeof(node));
        tmp->data = d;
        tmp->next = NULL;
        if (head == NULL) return tmp;

        node *end = head;

        while(end->next != NULL){
            end = end->next;
        }
        end->next = tmp;

        return head;
}
```

And in the functions `max`, `min` and `locInList` you have an unnecessary `tmp = malloc(sizeof(node));` which causes memory leaks.

Comment: Big thank you! I made these changes and it works up until I hit the min function. Now I will look into that issue. I am sure it is the loop.

Comment: @User_Unknown_3458 In the `min` function you shall move `tmp = tmp->next;` **outside** the `if` statement. That actually also applies to the `max` function

Answer (score 1):

```
    node *tmp = NULL;
    tmp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    tmp = head;
```

This code first sets `tmp` to `NULL`, then sets it to point to a newly-allocated node, then sets it to point to `head`. I have no idea what you're trying to do, but setting the same variable to three different values consecutively can't possibly be right.

```
    while(tmp->next != NULL){
            if(tmp->data > max){
            max = tmp->data;
            tmp = tmp->next;
                       }
                       }
```

This code only does the `tmp = tmp->next;` is `tmp->data > max`. That can't be right. As soon as you encounter an element smaller than any previous element, you'll repeat the outer `while` loop forever.

```
    node *tmp = NULL;
    node *end = head;
    tmp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    end = malloc(sizeof(node));
```

This code sets `tmp` to `NULL`, but two lines later changes its mind and sets it to point to a newly-allocated node. It sets `end` to equal `head` but then two lines later changes its mind and sets it to point to a newly-allocated node. Why set something to one value just to immediately set it to another? Why allocate two nodes in a function that adds one node to a linked list?

```
    while(end->next != NULL){
        end = end->next;
        end->next = tmp;
                  }
```

You want to attach the node to the end of the list. But you attach it *every* time you move from one node to another!